# Issues with dask compute() on labels predicted by KMeans

Tags: python, scikit-learn, dask, dask-ml

I am trying to use sklearn MiniBatchKMeans to cluster a fairly large dataset (150k samples and 150k features). I thought I could make things much faster using Incremental from dask_ml to fit my data in chunks. Here is a snippet of my code on a dummy dataset:

```
    from dask_ml.datasets import make_blobs
    from dask_ml.wrappers import Incremental
    from sklearn.cluster import MiniBatchKMeans
    import dask.array as da
    import dask

    dataset = da.random.random((150000, 150000), chunks = (1000, 1000))
    kmeans = MiniBatchKMeans(n_clusters = 3)
    inc = Incremental(kmeans).fit(dataset)
    predicted_labels = inc.predict(dataset).compute()
    print(predicted_labels)
```

The process gets killed at the compute() step. I didn't think running compute() on 150k points would be so intensive. It fails with this strange error:

```
ValueError: X has 150000 features, but MiniBatchKMeans is expecting 1000 
features as input.
```

I don't understand what the size MiniBatchKMeans features have to do with compute() on the labels

**EDIT**
After the first answer, I would like to clarify that I use compute() on the labels (**not the dataset!**) because I need them for some plotting operations. These values need to be on RAM in order to be used by matplotlib functions.

An array of (150k, ) should be able to fit comfortably on RAM, I am not sure why it fails!

Answer (score 0):

The process breaks down because the `compute()` method will bring the entire dataset to local RAM. See the [documentation](https://distributed.dask.org/en/latest/manage-computation.html#dask-collections-to-concrete-values):

> You can turn any dask collection into a concrete value by calling the `.compute()` method or `dask.compute(...)` function.

And further:

> However, this approach often breaks down if you try to bring the entire dataset back to local RAM.
>
> `>>> df.compute()  # MemoryError(...)`

This is also why you get a value error with mismatched sizes, as you will pass the entire dataset to the `predict()` method at once instead of passing the smaller chunks one by one. Remove the `compute()` statement and it will work fine:

```py
predicted_labels = inc.predict(dataset)
```

---

Since your goal seemed to be to "make things much faster", also note the following:

> Each block of a Dask Array is fed to the underlying estimator’s `partial_fit` method. **The training is entirely sequential, so you won’t notice massive training time speedups from parallelism**. In a distributed environment, you should notice some speedup from avoiding extra IO, and the fact that models are typically much smaller than data, and so faster to move between machines.

(from [here](https://ml.dask.org/incremental.html#incremental-meta-estimator))

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Of course it works when I do not call compute(). The idea was to get these labels on RAM because I need to do some plotting with them. I have no problems with execution time, however not being able to access the predicted labels is the issue

Comment: I also tried passing only a part of dataset, something like: inc.predict(dataset[:10, :])
but this also fails with the same error message